# Error using google.colab in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, upload, google-colaboratory

i was trying to upload a csv file from using anaconda notebooks but i get the error below.

[image]

trying to download a csv file and expected a text box allowing me to browse the files from my computer